# How to set more language in TTS android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

See image below

[image]

[image]

Please see the image..
First i press click to speak and after then open Radio button and select language..
when i select english language then must be convert in english. 
Simply i select one language then convert in same lame language.
Is possible? n how?

i will wait answer its urgent so asap.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***try this***

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

//**and write this code for language**

```
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK))

mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.FRANCE))

mTts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("spa", "ESP")))
```

//***Make your text for speack***

```
String myText1 = "Did you sleep well?";
String myText2 = "I hope so, because it's time to wake up.";
mTts.speak(myText1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
mTts.speak(myText2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```